# How do I properly push an array into a data object in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add multiple values into an existing data object `pathStats: []`

### Code:

```js
data () {
  return {
    pathStats: []
  }
}

computed: {
  loadDetails() {
    fse.stat('C:/').then((res) => {
      let edited = res.mtime
      let created = res.birthtime
      this.pathStats.push([{'edited': edited}, {'created': created}])
    })
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get the values separately when I need them, e.g.:

```html
<p>{{pathStats.edited}}</p>
<p>{{pathStats.created}}</p>
```

But with the current code, I get `undefined` when I try to console.log `pathStats.created` or `pathStats.edited`

Comment: `pathStats` is an array, but you're trying to grab an object property out of it. Try `pathStats[0][0].edited` instead, for example, to perform the operation on an element of the array.

Comment: But how do I save it in a form that would allow me to get it by name, like that:  `pathStats.edited` ?

Comment: Worse still, you're trying to push an array of objects where it doesn't make sense. If you want to make this simpler, try `push({'edited': edited, 'created': created})`.

Comment: Tell me this: is your intent to have a history of "path stats"? Or do you just want to update values in place? If you just want to update values in place, then you could do something like `Object.assign(this.pathStats, {'edited': edited, 'created': created});` and in your `data()`, define `pathStats: {}`. What this does is overwrites the values in the original `pathStats` object with the values in another object.

Comment: @B.Fleming Yes, that's what I needed, just to push the data there so I can easily grab it, thanks that `Object.assign` method does the job

Comment: @B.Fleming and thanks for explaining it!

Comment: If you ever need a full array of elements, you could also use the original `push({'edited': edited, 'created': created})` solution I noted previously, but then use a `computed` property to automatically retrieve the last object in the `pushStats` array. This allows you to keep a record of previous entries while also having the simple `computedPushStat.edited` syntax. Take whatever approach is most appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution, as per the discussion in the comments on the original question: Instead of using an array, just use an object and take advantage of `Object.assign()`.

```
data () {
  return {
    pathStats: {}
  }
}

computed: {
  loadDetails() {
    fse.stat('C:/').then((res) => {
      let edited = res.mtime
      let created = res.birthtime
      Object.assign(this.pathStats, {'edited': edited, 'created': created})
    })
  }
}
```

The method `Object.assign()` takes 2 or more arguments. The first is the object you want to write values to, and the remaining n-1 objects will write values into the destination object in order. In this case, `this.pathStats` will receive overriding values from the second object.

This solution also has the advantage of not needing to access array elements since an array is not what was desired.

Answer (score 1):

One way for this is:

How about having **pathStats** as an associative array.

```
data () {
  return {
    pathStats: {}
  }
}

computed: {
  loadDetails() {
    fse.stat('C:/').then((res) => {
      let edited = res.mtime
      let created = res.birthtime
      this.pathStats['edited'] = edited
      this.pathStats['created'] = created
    })
  }
}
```

And you can it this way.

```
{{pathStats.edited}}
{{pathStats.created}}
```

Or else (Not recommended though)

But if you want it only has an arrayList. You may want to get it through indices.

```
{{pathStats[0][0].edited}}
{{pathStats[0][0].created}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that works just as `Object.assign`, but it's not overwriting the current data in the array, so that's nice to know

Comment: Yeah even I would have probably accepted Object.assign. Thats a nice one.